PATCH not supported by the /tooling/sobjects/CustomField HTTP REST endpoint?
The Tooling API CustomField documentation says:

Supported SOAP Calls
create(), query(), retrieve(), search(), update(), upsert()
Supported REST HTTP Methods
Query, GET, POST, PATCH

but when I try a PATCH (or PUT) request using API 59.0 (and a System Administrator user) I get:

statusCode=405
status=Method Not Allowed
body=[("errorCode":"METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED","message":"HTTP Method 'PATCH' not allowed. Allowed are HEAD,GET,POST")]

which is frustrating. Is there something I'm missing? The POST request (using the same data) works.
I assume an update via the Metadata API will work?

PATCH is supported but the field Id must be appended to the URL. See e.g. Custom field update API.
Getting the field Id is described e.g. here Querying Custom Object and Field IDs via Tooling API. It amounts to two Tooling API queries, one of CustomObject and one of CustomField. So two extra steps for the "update" case compared to the "create" case.
